# My program's output changes when I add a printf statement

Tags: c, printf

I'm training a simple neural network in C.  When I go to evaluate it's performance it's not giving the same outputs as training.  I added a print statement to this loop to look at each hidden layer output.  Suddenly it's working.

```
evalSumO = WeightHO[0] ; //bias
for( hid = 1 ; hid <= numhidden ; hid++ ) {
  evalSumO += evalHidden[hid] * WeightHO[hid];
  //printf("%f ",evalHidden[nn][hid] * WeightHO[nn][hid]);
}

printf("evalSumO %f\n", evalSumO);
```

If I uncomment the printf statement the function outputs 3.6414 as expected.  If I comment it out it it gives a different number 11.2707 which is wrong.

Furthermore I've changed the printf statement to just `printf(" ");` and it also gives the correct number 3.6414.

I even tried to trick it by changing it to `printf("%s","")` thus printing nothing.  And it's broken again.  So, the act of printing something to stdout changes the value of evalSumO??

I've been programming in C for 30 years and I've never seen 'the observer effect' in a program.  So it must be a syntax error I just can't see.  What's going on?

Comment: Sounds a lot like you're overrunning a buffer somewhere and the `printf` changes the memory layout enough to make it seem like it's fine. Are you sure you want `<=` and not just `<`? Not enough code to know for sure. Try putting together a [mcve].

Comment: @EdwardKarak They'd get a syntax error in that case.

Comment: @EdwardKarak And these have been C-style comments for decades.

Comment: If you've never seen this when programming so long, you've been extremely lucky. This is a classic symptom of buffer overflows and other forms of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  You set me on the right track.  My  arrays contain numhidden+1 elements to give room of the 0 bias.  But, I forgot to add one on the evalHidden array.  That did it.   Still a very strange effect.

Comment: Just fyi, *"it must be a syntax error"* - if that were true your compiler would catch it. Syntax errors break compilation; logic errors break programs.

Comment: Try running valgrind to see if you are doing some sketchy memory allocation/usage. I once (unintentionally) allocated an array of size zero and used it. When I changed the layout of a struct, my program took longer to crash and produced different output.